# Proof of the inequality $|b_{n_0}-b_n| \leq \epsilon/2 $ implies $|b_n|\geq \epsilon/2$

Tags: inequality

The title is a passage from a proof that I'm studying, Shamefully, I'm having a hard time to fill this proof-gap:

> If $\lvert b_{n_0}-b_n\lvert \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then $\lvert b_n\rvert\geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

I don't know if it's necessary, but $\lvert b_{n_0}\rvert>\epsilon$.

Comment: Quite necessary, otherwise take $b_k = 0$ for e.g.

Answer (score 2):

One has $|x-y|\geq |x|-|y|$ for any real numbers $x$ and $y$.

So $$
\epsilon-|b_{n}|<|b_{n_0}|-|b_n|\leq |b_{n_0}-b_n|\leq \epsilon/2.$$ Rearranging gives $\epsilon/2\leq|b_n|$.